# WordPressMU - get blog list, alphabetically sorted by blogname

Tags: mysql, join, wordpress, wpmu

In WordPress MU, I've tried writing my own query for this but can't seem to get all of the joins I really need. The result set I'm looking for would be something like:

```
blog_id
blog name
blog path
owner first name
owner last name
```

and return it all alphabetically, by blog name. The trouble I'm having is that the first and last name of the blog owner are in wp_usermeta, the blog id and path are in wp_blogs, and the blog name is in wp_[blog id here]_options, with wp_usermeta requiring the user ID from wp_users.

Is it possible to join all of this in one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a way to combine all of the information into one result set because of the way WPMU handles the database table names.

The best solution I have come up with is some PHP logic that gets the blogs from the wp_blogs table, uses the IDs there to gather information from the wp_X_options tables, and then builds up the information I need. It's the same reason there is no good way to get a list of all the posts across all of the blogs with just a query. You need backend logic to build the query based on the blogs in wp_blogs.